# Execute Lua code in the background Freeswitch

Tags: lua, aws-cli, freeswitch

I'm writing some Lua code with Freeswitch and trying to execute some code while the main program continues execution.

I've tried

```
...
-- aws is AWS Command Line Interface
io.popen("aws s3 cp " ..  s3_src .. " ".. s3_dst)
os.execute("aws s3 cp " ..  s3_src .. " ".. s3_dst)
... -- program execution continues
```

Even tried  passing it off to a shell script(`s3_upload`)

```
os.execute("s3_upload " ..  s3_src .." " .. s3_dst)
io.popen("s3_upload " ..  s3_src .. " ".. s3_dst)
```

If i use the Lua Interactive shell to run these commands independently, it works.

would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: @lhf, Same thing. Nothing gets uploaded

Comment: Use `os.execute("sh -c ...")` to run a shell with your command as argument

Answer (score 0):

To execute a program in the background on *nix systems, append `&` to the command line.
So, try

```
os.execute("aws s3 cp " ..  s3_src .. " ".. s3_dst .. " &")
```